# Setting custom start/end x-axis on TIMEVALUE data

Tags: powerbi

I have a stacked bar chart which uses a DAX calculater TIMEVALUE as the x-axis as follows:

```
StartTimeValue = TIMEVALUE(Meetings[localStartDate])
```

I have gone into Modelling and set the format of the data to TIME and using format of HH:mm:ss. If I look at the actual data it is displayed correctly.

However, depending on the filters I choose, the x-axis of the stacked bar chart changes based on the distribution of the data. I want to fix the x-axis to a 24-hour period: 00:00:00 -> 23:59:59.  If I enter 00:00:00 in the Start box of the X-axis it goes red and is not accepted.

Any ideas on how to do this? What is it actually expecting in that field?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Interestingly if I set the format to date/time it shows the data as 30/12/1899 HH:mm:ss.   Why such a wierd date?

Comment: That looks like a negative time value converted to datetime since datetime is stored as the number of days since the beginning of 1900

Comment: yep - seems that TIMEVALUE DAX function is not working properly. datetimes given to TIMEVALUE are current so the input datetime is correct